# How to create JList and Gray Button When user select item from the list the button color change to black?

Tags: java, swing

Iam trying to make normal JList and when the user select item the button change, i guess if there is any action listener or something i could add? i don't actually know

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use a `ListSelectionListener`. It will generate an event every time the selection changes.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more information and working examples.